# What would you recommend for creating a Logging Project in VB.NET from zero?

Tags: .net, vb.net, logging

I've been assigned to start a new Logging Project from zero in VB.NET.

The final exit of the main project is information organized in paragraphs like this:

**Paragraph's title 1** 
  Paragraph's content 1.

**Paragraph's title 2** 
  Paragraph's content 2.

Every paragraph correspond to a database connection. Every connection is made with an entire diferent database.
i need my logging project to save everything the user does, so the logging exit would be like the system exit but with exceptions and other important information like this:

**Paragraph's title 1** 
  Paragraph's content 1.

**Paragraph's title 2** 
  User wasn't able to see this information because an exception ocurred: System.WhateverException:couldn't connect to WCF.

as you can see the exit is the same but i need to create a detail log because the information is delicate and the DBA needs to now wich user did what and what was the response of the system.

Also i need it to be and independant project so i can re-use it in another projects.

Seeing the final exit of both the main project and the logging project, what would you recommend me to use for logging in .NET?
Is there an example project?

Thank you.

Comment: Any specific reasons you cannot use [log4net](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/) or [NLog](http://nlog-project.org/) or something similar? I did a [post](http://blog4work.com/post/2010/12/30/Logging-with-log4net-using-stored-procedure.aspx) that use log4net and stored proc to log info into a database, maybe this would be relevant.

Comment: i can use both of them, i've been investigating but i can't seem to find an example project or something elaborated with any of them. I wanted to hear all your suggestions so i can have a better start point! i can't see your post because i have fortiguard in my job, as soon as i get home i'll read it! thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I would recomment using well known logging solution for .Net such as:

[NLog](http://nlog-project.org/) or
   [log4Net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/)

Personally I prefer NLog, For examples on how to use NLog check [this](http://nlog-project.org/wiki/Tutorial)